Ubuntu 24.04 Setting a single external display for laptop . . . Obtuse or not?
Since 24.04 came in, when you try to get a single external monitor using
Settings > Displays > Join tab
and then select the desired monitor at the Primary Display drop-down list.
Unlike 22.04 we can't choose a Single Display or Multiple Display button. So - ostensibly - we're stuck with having the built-in display of a laptop burning away even though we are just using a bigger external monitor.
This Reddit thread suggests a procedure involving joining the built-in display to an external one and then clicking on the unwanted display on the listing of displays in the Join tab, entering the mini-page for that, switching off that display, clicking Apply and afterwards clicking a button to confirm the changes.
Am I the only Ubie who finds this routine obtuse ?
To me, the old way used in 22.04 LTS was clearer for users already sufficiently challenged by their daily work.

No you're not. I was also confused, and turning off the trigger button in mini page was the only way I found (at first I thought there may be a more straightforward UX by installing the Gnome-Tweak package, but not a fan of installing unnecessary softwares for no reason).
